# Loading object and displaying data

Tags: java

I made a class that saves and loads objects for my Othello game project. My question is how do I take this saved object and display the saved game board state within it? Thanks in advance for the answers by the way!

```
public class SaveGame {

public static final String filename = "gameSave.bin";

public void saveGameFile(Serializable object){

    FileOutputStream fs = null;


    try{
        fs = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
        os.writeObject(object);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void load(){
    if(checkFileExists()){
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        try{

            fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            CreateBoard cb = (CreateBoard) ois.readObject();

            ois.close();

            System.out.println(cb.toString());

        }catch(ClassNotFoundException | IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public  boolean checkFileExists(){
    return new File(filename).isFile(); //Searches directory to make sure file exists
}
```

Comment: R u creating a console based game or a Swing based or GUI based application.

Comment: If you are creating a Console based, then you have to just create a nested for loops to print the state. Print 0, if not filled, Print 1 or X for player 1 occupied, Print 2 or Y for player 2.

Comment: I'd imagine i'll have to override the toString function to do this?

Comment: According to me, CreateBoard must be containing a 2D array to store the state of all position.

Comment: Yes, you can override the toString() method, And, in toString() method, just print thee 2D array using loops.

Comment: Yes, the CreateBoard Class has methods for printing the board and adding game pieces to the board too.

Comment: Ok, fine then you have to just call those method inside toString().

Comment: Ok, that's brilliant thanks.

Comment: You can even write System.out.println(cb); and this code will automatically call toString() overriden method.

Comment: If you liked my answer, accept it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help Ashish :)